# How to setup environment to run multiple lambdas that invoke each other locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that invokes other lambdas and that's working fine. I want to set this up on my localhost now so I can test the interaction between the lambdas locally before deploying. This is the code I'm using to invoke the other lambda from the first lambda.

```
exports.route = async (req) => {
    const functionName = getFunctionName(req.body.data); // logic involving recursion parses the data to see which type of function it is.
    await client.send(
        new InvokeCommand({
            FunctionName: functionName,
            InvocationType: 'Event',
            Payload: JSON.stringify({
                body: req.body,
                headers: req.headers
            })
        })
    );
}
```

Is there a way to run the lambdas and have this route locally when I'm testing on localhost? I am able to run the first lambda locally, but it invokes the deployed lambda and not my local lambda.

This is how I'm running the first lambda

```
sam build -m package.json
sam local start-api --host 0.0.0.0 --warm-containers EAGER
```

This is how I'm running the second lambda

```
sam build -m package.json
sam local start-lambda --host 0.0.0.0 --warm-containers EAGER
```

The way I'm planning to test is by running `ngrok http` on localhost and pointing a dev version of my bot there. Then I can send test commands to the dev bot and that then forwards the events to my localhost that invokes the first lambda that then routes to the second lambda running on localhost.

Is this the wrong way to test lambdas?

*Update*

To get the routing lambda to invoke the local version of the lambdas I updated the LambdaClient initialization object to point to localhost like this.

```
const lambdaOptions = process.env.env === "prod" ? undefined : {
    apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
    endpoint: 'http://192.168.0.xxx:3001', // my internal ip address
    sslEnabled: false,
    region: 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId: 'any',
    secretAccessKey: 'any'
};

const client = new LambdaClient(lambdaOptions);
```

This points the lambda to my localhost, but the `InvocationType: 'Event'` feature is not available

Here's a github conversation about the issue.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/pull/749

Comment: For managing multiple lambda function, step functions are usually used.

Comment: @Marcin Those step functions look interesting. Is there a way to make a decision node that would route to the right lambda based on input from an api gateway? The first lambda has an api gateway that receives all the different payloads for different lambdas. That lambda looks at the payload and routes it to the lambda that has the logic to handle it. Would it be possible to do something like this with step functions?

Comment: Probably you could do it, but I'm not sure of details now.

Comment: @Marcin I looked into the step functions a bit more. I found this `A Choice state adds branching logic to a state machine. Choice rules can implement 16 different comparison operators, and can be combined using And, Or, and Not`. If I refactored the `getFunctionName()` into it's own lambda I could then route based on function name, but that requires me to manually hook up each function. Right now it's dynamic and I'd like to keep it that way so I don't need to update a step function config every time I create a new command. I updated my question a bit to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

Since `InvocationType: 'Event'` is not currently supported when running lambdas locally, I ended up creating a simple nodejs express app to mimic the behavior of the first lambda. With express it is possible to send a response and continue processing unlike lambdas. So I changed `InvocationType` to `RequestResponse` and moved the invoking of the second lambdas to after the `res.send()` express call is made.